# Error - 'global symbol requires explicit package name'

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script for matrix multiplication. Its just a basic program but I am not able to figure it out about the following error :

Global symbol "@ref_mat1" requires explicit package name at multiplication.pl line 49.

Global symbol "@ref_mat2" requires explicit package name at multiplication.pl line 49.

Below is my script :

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;

     my @mat1=(
        [2,3,4],
        [1,2,3],
        [3,4,5]
            );

    my @mat2=(
            [2],
            [3],
            [4]
           );


    my ($i, $j, $k);
    my $r_product=[];

   $r_product= mat_multiplication(\@mat1,\@mat2);

    sub mat_multiplication
        {

         my ($ref_mat1,$ref_mat2)=@_;
         my($mat1_row,$mat1_col)=total_rows_column($ref_mat1);
         my($mat2_row,$mat2_col)=total_rows_column($ref_mat2);
             for($i=0;$i<$mat1_row;$i++)
            {
               for($j=0;$j<$mat2_col;$j++)
                {
                   my $sum=0;
                   for($k=0;$k<$mat1_col;$k++)
                    {
                      $sum=$sum+$ref_mat1[$i][$k]*$ref_mat2[$k][$j];
                    }
                    $r_product->[$1][$j]=$sum;
                }
            } 
            return $r_product;

        }


    sub total_rows_column
             { 
              my($r_mat) =@_;
              my $num_row=@{$r_mat};
              my $num_col=@{$r_mat->[0]};
              return($num_row,$num_col);
             }
```

I searched for this problem and found one link

[Explanation of 'global symbol requires explicit package name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592770/explanation-of-global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

But still not able to resolve it. Please just have a look an let me know where am i doing mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to accept questions .That is the reason i did not do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$ref_mat1` and `$ref_mat2` are references to arrays. In Perl if you want to access a reference to an array you cannot use `$reference[$idx]` directly -- you have to use the `->` operator after the reference like this: `$ref_mat1->[0]`.

Without it Perl thinks that `$ref_mat1[0]` refers to an array `@ref_mat1` which doesn't exist. Yes, both `$var` and `@var` can exist at the same time with differing content, see this example:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $abc = 42;
my @abc = (1, 2, 3);

print Dumper($abc), Dumper(\@abc);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution - I had the same error, but I was using a Hash instead of an array, made me try your solution and it worked!