# Debugging Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

This is my first encounter with Perl. I know this question has been asked earlier and I have checked

[Global symbol requires explicit package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141412/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

[Explanation of 'global symbol requires explicit package name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592770/explanation-of-global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name)

[Why does Perl say Global symbol "SYMBOL" requires explicit package name at PROGRAM.pl line X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257179/why-does-perl-say-global-symbol-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name-at-progr)

But I am unable to find error in my code. I am tasked to debug this. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
package foo;



use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;


sub extract {
    my $fname = shift
        or warn("provide the XML file to load\n"),
           return;

    my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $fname);
    my ($nvd)  = $xml->nonBlankChildNodes;

    my @vuln;
    for my $entry ($nvd->nonBlankChildNodes) {
        my %value;
        # %value = parse_nvd_entry($entry);

        for my $attr ($entry->attributes) {
            $value{$attr->nodeName} = $attr->nodeValue;
        }

        # rename 'name' to 'cve_id'
        my $cve_id = $value{cve_id} = delete $value{name};
        
        $vuln{$cve_id} = \%value;
    }

    return  %vuln;
}
```

This package is called and invoked here

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib qq($FindBin::Bin/../lib);

use foo;
use Dumpvalue;

if (@ARGV != 1) {
   die "Extract vulnerability records into database file\n",
       "Usage:\n    $0 <NVD_XML_files>\n\n";
}

my %vuln = foo::extract(@ARGV);

Dumpvalue->new->dumpValue(\%vuln);
```

The script produces this output:

> Global symbol "%vuln" requires explicit package name at /Users/dev/projects/software/foo/scripts/../lib/foo.pm line 35.
>
> Global symbol "%vuln" requires explicit package name at /Users/dev/projects/software/foo/scripts/../lib/foo.pm line 38.

Comment: Tip: Replace `$FindBin::Bin` with `$FindBin::RealBin`. The former is broken for symbolic links to your script.

Comment: Tip: You can't actually return a hash from a sub (just scalars), so you are actually returning a the keys and values of the hash and creating a new hash on the outside. One would normally return a reference to the hash instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a hash named `%vuln` you never declared.

```
$vuln{$cve_id} = \%value;
```

```
return %vuln;
```

You declared an array named `@vuln` you never use.

```
my @vuln;
```

Replace that declaration with

```
my %vuln;
```

Comment: you sir, are a savior.
but now I get this:
foo.pm did not return a true value at invoking file(nvd_extract.pl) line 12.

Comment: Add `1;` to the bottom of the module. Modules must return a true value.